# In Ada (GNAT), using pragma Overflow_Mod / infinite precision intermediate calculations

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to convert a (small) numerator and denominator to a numerator in terms of a large constant denominator, chosen to be divisible by most small numbers and to be just under 2**63. Since that's likely to overflow, I'll use pragma Overflow_Mode (Eliminated) (cf. the GNAT 4.8 manual http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Specifying-the-Desired-Mode.html#Specifying-the-Desired-Mode).

```
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Example is
    pragma Overflow_Mode (Eliminated);
    Large_Composite : constant := (2 ** 7) * (3 ** 5) * (5 ** 2) * 7 
            * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41;
    type Word_Unsigned is mod 2**64;
N, D : Integer;
begin
    N := Integer'Value (Ada.Command_Line.Argument (1));
    D := Integer'Value (Ada.Command_Line.Argument (2));
    Ada.Text_IO.Put (Word_Unsigned ((N * Large_Composite) / D)'Img);
end Example;
```

Unfortunately, when trying to compile the example code (and the real code it's a distillation of) with "~/bin/gcc-4.8.0/bin/gnatmake -gnat12 -gnata -Wall example.adb" (and with -gnato3, though that should be redundant to the pragma), the compiler says:

```
example.adb:12:46: value not in range of type "Standard.Integer"
example.adb:12:46: static expression fails Constraint_Check
gnatmake: "example.adb" compilation error
```

Hrumph. Am I not understanding what Overflow_Mode does? Is there some easy way to rearrange this so it works? (I can go to plan A, a more normal fraction class that may or may not be faster or plan B, just using floats and accepting that 1/3 will get rounded, but I'd like this to work. Proper infinite-length integer support is overkill here.)

Comment: Could you use a fixed-point type with a delta of 1?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer, but using Long_Long_Integer, which is large enough to hold Large_Composite, instead of Integer suppresses the warnings, and pragma Overflow_Mode does its job and lets me use stuff like N = 99 and D = 100 and get the right answer. This computational model still seems somewhat inconsistent, but at least the code is working.

Comment: I think the problem is that the error occurs at compile time, whereas `-gnato3` says how to handle run time processing. If you declare `N` and `D` as `Word_Unsigned` the program works with N = 100000000000000000 and D = 1 (even without the pragma).

Comment: In my real code, if N is larger then D, I take N mod D. If I take N = 99 and D = 100, then using Long_Long_Integer and the pragma I get 7807305162319030368 which bc (and the naked eye) tells me is 99% of the Large_Composite = 7886166830625283200. If I use Word_Unsigned, then 99 * Large_Composite = 5967265136101868900 (mod 2**64), and dividing that by 100 gets us 59672651361018689, which is not the right answer.

Comment: ... but my suggestion doesn't provide the signed multiply you wanted. Sorry (the compile-time point stands, though).

Comment: I think I'm getting the distinction between compile time and run time processing here. I think it's somewhat inconsistent, but given that Overflow_Mode is a new feature and it's all an extension to the base Ada numeric model, that's understandable.